# Package Community Template

Tags: community, managed-package, package, community-template

I'm investigating how to **package a Community Template**. I created a test Community template (from the Napili template) in my dev org, exported it, added it to my package, and pulled all the default metadata.

In a different org I enabled Communities, Chatter, made the user a Chatter user, and created a test community based on the Napili template. But when I try deploying the package to this org I get the following errors:

```
1.  flexipages/Advisor_Link_Topic_Detail.flexipage -- Error: Component Access denied to component selfService:topicTrendingArticles (line 121, column 29)
2.  flexipages/Advisor_Link_Question_Detail.flexipage -- Error: Component Access denied to component selfService:topicTrendingArticles (line 86, column 29)
3.  flexipages/Advisor_Link_Home.flexipage -- Error: Component Access denied to component selfService:topicTrendingArticles (line 127, column 29)
4.  flexipages/Advisor_Link_Article_Detail.flexipage -- Error: The object type you specified CaseArticle is invalid.
5.  communityTemplateDefinitions/Advisor_Link.communityTemplateDefinition -- Error: In field: Page - no FlexiPage named Advisor_Link_Article_Detail found
```

The first one says that the [Topic Trending Articles](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rss_topic_trending_articles.htm#rss_topic_trending_articles) component cannot be accessed. But I see it's there if I go to the Community Builder for the test Community I created. And I don't see any setting to enable it. Is there any configuration of any sort that is necessary to make this component available?

Comment: Try adding access="global" to all the components .Most of issues might be due to that

Comment: @MohithShrivastava topicTrendingArticles is a standard component that was already in the org. I did not create it, did not get pulled down when retrieving the metadata, and I don't see any way to change its properties.

Comment: Advisor_Link_Topic_Detail is this your custom builder page ? Note that try to assemble only the custom components in that page

Comment: Ok, a coworker gave me solution (so I won't answer it myself to get extra points): you have to enable Knowledge at the org level. Just making the user that is deploying the package a Knowledge user is not enough.

Comment: answer that as that helps the community looking for this error .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A coworker gave me solution: you have to **enable Knowledge at the org level**. `Under Setup > Customize > Knowledge > Knowledge Settings`. Just making the user that is deploying the package a Knowledge user is not enough, but you need that user perm enabled to be able to enable Knowledge at the org level.

Comment: how come I am unable to see Knowledge in Setup? ...