# The object type you specified CaseArticle is invalid

Tags: managed-package

Our 1gp managed package is failing during installation with:

> 1. (EO_Community_Article_Detail) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s) There were custom validation error(s) encountered while
>    saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered
>    was "The object type you specified CaseArticle is invalid.".

The package contains a custom (Customer Service) experience site template which it seems like it is causing the error. How would you solve this installation error?

Comment: Take a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146756/package-community-template

Comment: @identigral orgs without Knowledge license are not elegible for installing packages that contain a Customer Service template?

Comment: The template is just a shell, perms to object (`CaseArticle`) is where the rubber of the license meets the road. Case Article requires [Knowledge](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.knowledge_setup_users_lex.htm&type=5) which is either bundled or available at an additional cost. The Knowledge feature is a checkbox on User. You may not need the Knowledge license for read-only use cases. All of the above is true for non-packaged access. Packaging adds an extra layer of complexity. See if your customer could create the Exp site with this template and no package.

Comment: When investigating how to provide a packageable experience site I received (on the partner forums) several recommendations not to do so in a managed package but instead to use an unlocked package, due to numerous issues seen with managed packages. It must be said, this was for a site, not a template. I didn't want a template because I would have to manage both the original site definition and a template generated from it which struck me as dumb, but also precludes any later upgrading of the site generated from the packaged template.